# chop or rtrim not removing last character

Tags: php

I want to **chop off the last comma** but its not working.
earlier today exact these lines were working in a different code block.

```
if($added_attr > $original_attribute)
    {

        for($i = $original_attribute;$i<$added_attr;$i++)
        {
             echo $attribute_data .= "('$id','$attr_changed[$original_attribute]','$attr_val[$original_attribute]'),";
        }

        $attribute_data = chop($attribute_data , ",");
        $sql_new_insert = "INSERT INTO product_attribute_value(iProductId,iAttributeId,vValue)".
                        "VALUES ".$attribute_data;
    }
```

Well, this is surprise as this is working now with out a edit to any character. Even in morning it same thing happened, rtrim,chop,substr did not worked for 30 min. though my problem is solved now, any solution this problem will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Did you initialized your variable? Add error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` and tell us if you get any errors

Comment: have you tried `rtrim`??

Comment: yeah, i have initialised error and tried both rtrim and substr.

Comment: try like this echo rtrim($attribute_data,',');

Comment: @NishantSolanki `chop` is an alias of `rtrim`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.chop.php

Comment: @sajansahoo have you tried echoing your query?? so we can know wether the comma is getting removed or not

Comment: Protip: Don't `.=`, instead `$values[] = ".."`, then `join(', ' $values)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$attribute_data = array();
for($i = $original_attribute;$i<$added_attr;$i++)
{
   $attribute_data[] = "('$id','$attr_changed[$original_attribute]','$attr_val[$original_attribute]')";
}
echo implode(',',$attribute_data);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

You can try this way